# Logging into wso2ei 6.1.1 via Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server

I'm looking for a way to log into wso2ei business-process using wso2is.
I'm following this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Logging+in+to+WSO2+Products+via+the+Identity+Server) but not found any guide for wso2ei.
Any ideas?

Comment: EI is the successor of the ESB, you might try the ESB guide.

Comment: I tried but I did not find anything. I enabled SAML2SSOAuthenticator in wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/business-process/conf/security/authenticators.xml but have this error :Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.common.builders.SignKeyDataHolder.<init>(SignKeyDataHolder.java:46)
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.common.builders.AuthenticationRequestBuilder.buildAuthenticationRequest(AuthenticationRequestBuilder.java:123)